# lenovo x200 arch hibernate not working

Tags: arch-linux, hibernate

I'm running up to date arch + i3 on my lenovo x200. The only thing that doesnt work is hibernate.

What I did so far:

- changed GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to:
  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=Linux zswap.enabled=1 zswap.compressor=lz4 resume=/dev/disk/by-uuid/79abb13e-0fcf-47a4-bb0f-f3a461d385ee resume_offset=188416"` 
  after reading [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation) (I'm using a swap file so I needed to add "resume_offset")
- blacklisted modules "mei_me" and "mei" after seeing the error described [in arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X200#pciehp_0000:00:1c.1:pcie04:_Cannot_add_device_at_0000:03:00)

Hibernation still doesn't work. It seems like its putting the PC to sleep but after booting it is just like a normal startup and not restoring anything saved on harddisk.
Any Hints?
I checked dmesg and found:

```
[    3.132571] PM: Checking hibernation image partition /dev/disk/by-uuid/79abb13e-0fcf-47a4-bb0f-f3a461d385ee
[    3.132574] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
```

Output of filefrag -v /swapfile:

```
Filesystem type is: ef53
File size of /swapfile is 3670016000 (896000 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..       0:     188416..    188416:      1:            
   1:        1..   30719:     188417..    219135:  30719:             unwritten
   2:    30720..   40959:     219136..    229375:  10240:             unwritten
   3:    40960..   71679:     231424..    262143:  30720:     229376: unwritten
   4:    71680..  102399:     262144..    292863:  30720:             unwritten
   5:   102400..  104447:     292864..    294911:   2048:             unwritten
   6:   104448..  135167:     296960..    327679:  30720:     294912: unwritten
   7:   135168..  165887:     327680..    358399:  30720:             unwritten
   8:   165888..  196607:     358400..    389119:  30720:             unwritten
   9:   196608..  227327:     389120..    419839:  30720:             unwritten
  10:   227328..  258047:     419840..    450559:  30720:             unwritten
  11:   258048..  288767:     450560..    481279:  30720:             unwritten
  12:   288768..  319487:     481280..    511999:  30720:             unwritten
  13:   319488..  331775:     512000..    524287:  12288:             unwritten
  14:   331776..  362495:     612352..    643071:  30720:     524288: unwritten
  15:   362496..  393215:     643072..    673791:  30720:             unwritten
  16:   393216..  423935:     673792..    704511:  30720:             unwritten
  17:   423936..  454655:     704512..    735231:  30720:             unwritten
  18:   454656..  485375:     735232..    765951:  30720:             unwritten
  19:   485376..  516095:     765952..    796671:  30720:             unwritten
  20:   516096..  538623:     796672..    819199:  22528:             unwritten
  21:   538624..  569343:     821248..    851967:  30720:     819200: unwritten
  22:   569344..  600063:     851968..    882687:  30720:             unwritten
  23:   600064..  602111:     882688..    884735:   2048:             unwritten
  24:   602112..  632831:     886784..    917503:  30720:     884736: unwritten
  25:   632832..  663551:     917504..    948223:  30720:             unwritten
  26:   663552..  694271:     948224..    978943:  30720:             unwritten
  27:   694272..  724991:     978944..   1009663:  30720:             unwritten
  28:   724992..  755711:    1009664..   1040383:  30720:             unwritten
  29:   755712..  763903:    1040384..   1048575:   8192:             unwritten
  30:   763904..  794623:    1128448..   1159167:  30720:    1048576: unwritten
  31:   794624..  825343:    1159168..   1189887:  30720:             unwritten
  32:   825344..  856063:    1189888..   1220607:  30720:             unwritten
  33:   856064..  886783:    1220608..   1251327:  30720:             unwritten
  34:   886784..  895999:    1251328..   1260543:   9216:             last,unwritten,eof
/swapfile: 7 extents found
```

Output of lsblk -f:

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL             UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                  
├─sda1 ntfs   System-reserviert 4CFAF5F7FAF5DCE0                     
├─sda2 ntfs   SYSTEM            701005C8100595EE                     
└─sda3 ext4                     79abb13e-0fcf-47a4-bb0f-f3a461d385ee /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solution found: I forgot to add "resume" to the hooks in "/etc/mkinitcpio.conf" and generate a new ramdisk with "mkinitcpio -p linux". All stated in the Arch wiki link about suspend and hibernation (see above).